# Google Maps mixed results for ATM and Banks

Tags: google-maps

When I search for nearby ATM at a particular latitude and longitude I get top 20 results but, the results are mix of ATM and the Banks. Why do I get a mixed result and, as I am not interested in bank results, how can I modify my search?

Below is the nearby search result.

[image]

Comment: it's probably because there are ATM in the bank....